# What is the idiomatic way to test an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

What is the idiomatic way to perform in-memory integration testing of a directive?

For example, say I have a directive that contains a button that when clicked changes color, would the following be idiomatic for a DOM integration test?

**colored-button-directive-spec.js**

```
var ColoredButtonDirective = require('../colored-button-directive');

describe('colored button', function() {

    var $compile, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache, $rootScope, $injector) {
      // Should configuration of the module be located in the beforeEach?   
      angular.module('test', [])
            .directive('coloredButton', ColoredButtonDirective);
        $templateCache.put('./colored-button.html');            
        $compile = $injector.get('$compile'); // Can I have $compile injected instead?
    }));

    it('should turn red when clicked', function() {
        //arrange
        var dom, button;
        dom = $compile(angular.element('<colored-button></colored-button>'))($rootScope); // Must I inject a scope to the invocation of the link function?
        button = angular.element(dom.querySelector('button')); // Is there a better way of getting the button inside the rendered DOM?

        //act
        button.click();

        //assert
        expect(button.css('background-color')).toBe('red');
    });

});
```

**colored-button.html**

```
<button ng-click='onClick'>My button</button>
```

**colored-button-directive.js**

```
return function ColoredButtonDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            onClick: function($event) {
                $event.currentTarget.css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: require('./colored-button.html'),
        replace: true,
    };
};
```

Comment: I would just go to [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/test/ng/directive). There are a number of directives there which have tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to address your questions in the comments:

> ```
> // Should configuration of the module be located in the beforeEach?   
> angular.module('test', [])
>   .directive('coloredButton', ColoredButtonDirective);
> ```

The more idiomatic way would be to do

```
beforeEach(module('test'));
```

as shown at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/guide/unit-testing . So the line instantiating your app from your real code

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
```

must be run in the test environment.

> $compile = $injector.get('$compile'); // Can I have $compile injected instead?

Yes, like

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $compile = _$compile_;
}));
```

Injecting a scope into `$compile`

> ```
> dom = $compile(angular.element('<colored-button></colored-button>'))($rootScope); // Must I inject a scope to the invocation of the link function?
> ```

Yes, you must. You could, if you want, compile an element once and then link against different scopes to have different DOM elements from the same compiled version. (I think this is what `ng-repeat` does under the hood).

> ```
> button = angular.element(dom.querySelector('button')); // Is there a better way of getting the button inside the rendered DOM?
> ```

I suspect yes, but as written I suspect the line doesn't work, for 2 reasons:

- `dom` is a `jQlite` object that doesn't have a `querySelector` method
- `dom` is a `jQlite` object of the root of the directive, which in your case is a button, so finding a button wouldn't find anything.

However, if you have a different DOM structure, you could do the following:

```
button = dom.find('button');
```

Also you didn't ask, but

> ```
> //act
> button.click();
> ```

Wouldn't work, as `jQlite` doesn't have a 'click' function. You could do:

```
dom.triggerHandler('click');
```

Also,

> ```
> scope: {
>   onClick: function($event) {
>     $event.currentTarget.css('background-color', 'red');
>   }
> }
> ```

wouldn't work, since this just isn't how the `scope` object is used in the directive definition. To work, this would have to be in the link function, and then also use `$event.target` instead

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.onClick = function($event) {
    angular.element($event.target).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
}
```

and then to get it to run, and pass the `$event` object, the template, instead of

> ```
> <button ng-click='onClick'>My button</button>
> ```

would have to be

```
<button ng-click='onClick($event)'>My button</button>
```

Putting this all together, you get a directive like

```
app.directive('coloredButton', function ColoredButtonDirective() {
  return {
    scope: {
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="onClick($event)">My button</button>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.onClick = function($event) {
        angular.element($event.target).css('background-color', 'red');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

and test like:

```
describe('colored button', function() {
  var $compile, $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('test'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
  }));

  it('should turn red when clicked', function() {
    var dom, button;
    dom = $compile(angular.element('<colored-button></colored-button>'))($rootScope);
    dom.triggerHandler('click');
    expect(dom.css('background-color')).toBe('red');
  });
```

});

which can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/L50B59V826Z6Wm8WtgJe?p=preview

---

However, there are alternative ways of writing, and so testing, this directive.

An alternative would be to not have query selectors in the linking function at all, and instead set some state on the scope on click, which the template then uses.

```
app.directive('coloredButton', function ColoredButtonDirective() {
  return {
    scope: {
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="onClick()" ng-style="{\'background-color\': isRed ? \'red\' : \'\'}">My button</button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.isRed = false;
      scope.onClick = function() {
        scope.isRed = true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

This means that the linking function doesn't depend on the DOM structure, and your one test can be replaced by three that

- test that on button click, a certain scope function is called
- test that the scope function sets some state on the scope
- test that if the scope has some state, the button is a certain colour

Note I have deliberately removed the `replace: true` in the definition, for 2 reasons:

- It's deprecated
- 2 of the 3 tests then do require finding the button, so it's closer to a non-trivial example

The tests themselves could then be written as

```
describe('colored button', function() {
  var $compile, $rootScope, dom, button, $scope;

  beforeEach(module('test'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
    dom = $compile(angular.element('<colored-button></colored-button>'))($rootScope);
    button = dom.find('button');
    $scope = dom.isolateScope();
  });

  it('should call the onClick handler', function() {
    spyOn($scope, 'onClick');
    expect($scope.onClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    button.triggerHandler('click');
    expect($scope.onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('the onClick handler should set isRed to be true', function() {
    expect($scope.isRed).toBe(false);
    $scope.onClick();
    expect($scope.isRed).toBe(true);
  });

  it('setting isRed true should make the button red', function() {
    expect(button.css('background-color')).not.toBe('red');
    $scope.isRed = true;
    $scope.$apply();
    expect(button.css('background-color')).toBe('red');
  });
});
```

Which can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/MmZGsYLopYP876Ft6ONG?p=preview

This would make your tests more "unit-y", which admittedly might not be what you want to achieve if you want to test a complete flow from click to effect in a single test. However, you still could combine the 3 tests into 1 to test their integration if that's what you want:

```
it('clicking should make the button red', function() {
  expect(button.css('background-color')).not.toBe('red');
  button.triggerHandler('click');
  expect(button.css('background-color')).toBe('red');
});
```

which can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/5WHzzzbpNFdqd94ITT8Q?p=preview